# PARSENAME function behaves wierd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

When I use the `PARSENAME` function in a Stored Procedure, sometimes it returns the correct value and sometimes it returns a `NULL` value. I'm bit confused here what would be the reason?

```
SELECT parsename(Replace('the big bang Theory',' ','.'),4)
```

Comment: This returns 'the' successfully on every run. Please check your source data whether you have two spaces in the data...

Comment: i'm not sure you are using this method correctly, please refer to the documentation for examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

> PARSENAME (Transact-SQL) Returns the specified part of an object name.
>   The parts of an object that can be retrieved are the object name,
>   owner name, database name, and server name.
>
> PARSENAME ( 'object_name' , object_piece )    Arguments 'object_name'
>   Is the name of the object for which to retrieve the specified object
>   part. object_name is sysname. This parameter is an
>   optionally-qualified object name. If all parts of the object name are
>   qualified, this name can have four parts: the server name, the
>
> > database name, the owner name, and the object name.
>
> object_piece Is the object part to return. object_piece is of type
>   int, and can have these values: 1 = Object name 2 = Schema name 3 =
>   Database name 4 = Server name

```
SELECT PARSENAME('[Server].database.schema.table', 1) AS 'Object Name';  
SELECT PARSENAME('[Server].database.schema.table', 2) AS 'Schema Name';  
SELECT PARSENAME('[Server].database.schema.table', 3) AS 'Database Name';  
SELECT PARSENAME('[Server].database.schema.table', 4) AS 'Server Name'; 

SELECT PARSENAME('database..table', 1) AS 'Object Name';  
SELECT PARSENAME('database..table', 2) AS 'Schema Name';  -- will return NULL
SELECT PARSENAME('database..table', 3) AS 'Database Name';  
SELECT PARSENAME('database..table', 4) AS 'Server Name'; -- will return NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all [`PARSENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) was intended to parse `object_name` of type `SYSNAME`.

Possible scenarios:

```
SELECT c, PARSENAME(REPLACE(sub.c, ' ', '.'), 4) AS part
FROM  (
    SELECT 'a b c d e'                 -- more than 4 parts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a b c d'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REPLICATE('a', 129) + ' b c d'  -- too long part
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REPLICATE('a', 128) + ' b c d'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a b c  d'                  -- more than one space
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('a b c d' AS CHAR(30)) -- padded with spaces
)sub(c)
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/TWOYNA10237)**

Keep in mind that `a.b.c.d.e` is not valid object_name. Also `SYSNAME` is alias for `NVARCHAR(128)` so longer parts will be invalid.

**The point is that when you use it to do different job (parsing any user string) you may get error.**